# Microphone goes mute on Pocophone F1 when opening any game while in a phone call

Tags: calls, miui, mute, xiaomi-pocophone-f1

Using Xiaomi Pocophone F1 (MIUI 11.0.8 Global). I abruptly go into **mute** when I boot up any games while in a normal phone call. This doesn't happen in other apps.

I tried denying microphone permissions for the game (Phone permission wasn't required in there). Experienced this issue in Call of Duty Mobile, Head Ball 2, etc.

Does Game Turbo have anything to do with this issue? I can still hear them while gaming, whereas I'm muted until I exit the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I too have that problem. I disabled Game Turbo and calls are working fine.